# How to install Snowflake's ODBC driver on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, odbc, ubuntu-18.04, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to install Snowflake's ODBC driver on an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu and having trouble doing it.

The configuration for the machine is `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-1045-aws x86_64)`

I'm following the instructions in their documentation - https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/odbc-linux.html and the steps I have taken are as follows

Prerequisites - I'm using unixODBC and I have verified that it has been installed.

`which odbcinst` returns `/usr/bin/odbcinst` and `which isql` returns `/usr/bin/isql`

Step 1 - I skipped verifying package signature because it was optional, but I'm reasonably sure this isn't the cause of not being able to successfully install

Step 2 - I first tried the DEB installer by downloading the right driver from https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/odbc/linux/latest/index.html by running `sudo wget https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/odbc/linux/latest/index.html` in my home directory of `/home/ubuntu`

After this I ran `sudo dpkg -i snowflake-odbc-2.19.13.x86_64.deb` as per the instructions. This fails with the following error/console log.

```
(Reading database ... 198004 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack snowflake-odbc-2.19.13.x86_64.deb ...
SnowflakeDSIIDriver has been deleted (if it existed at all) because its usage count became zero
odbcinst: DSN removed (if it existed at all). ODBC_SYSTEM_DSN was used as the search path.
Unpacking snowflake-odbc (2.19.13) over (2.19.13) ...
Setting up snowflake-odbc (2.19.13) ...
[WARN] SF_ACCOUNT is not set, please manually update the odbc.ini file after installation
Adding driver info to odbcinst.ini...
odbcinst: Driver installed. Usage count increased to 1.
    Target directory is /etc
Adding connect info to odbc.ini...
odbcinst: Sections and Entries from stdin have been added to ODBC.INI
Adding Simba Snowflake ini...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/snowflake-odbc.postinst: line 46: /usr/lib/snowflake/odbc/lib/simba.snowflake.ini: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/lib/snowflake/odbc/lib/simba.snowflake.ini: No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/snowflake-odbc.postinst: line 70: /usr/lib/snowflake/odbc/lib/simba.snowflake.ini: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package snowflake-odbc (--install):
 installed snowflake-odbc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 snowflake-odbc
```

Next step, I thought I would try the TGZ method. First I cleaned up the `/etc/odbcinst.ini` and `/etc/odbc.ini` files where the Snowflake details were added and brought it back to its original version.

Step 2 (Attempt 2) - I now downloaded the TGZ file using `sudo wget https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/odbc/linux/latest/snowflake_linux_x8664_odbc-2.19.13.tgz` once again in my home directory of `/home/ubuntu` and chose to install it in the same directory because I need my user to be able to write into the log directory.

After running `gunzip snowflake_linux_x8664_odbc-2.19.13.tgz` and `tar -xvf snowflake_linux_x8664_odbc-2.19.13.tar` I have extracted the folder which now sits under `/home/ubuntu/snowflake_odbc`.

Step 3 - Moving on the configuring the environment step. I choose the unixODBC method and execute `sudo ./unixodbc_setup.sh` as per the instructions. It seems to install successfully with the following console log

```
Prerequisites:
- install unixODBC
    - RedHat:  sudo yum install unixODBC
        - this package contains isql which can connect to Snowflake DB.
- adjust parameters in this file if needed
- make sure you are running this file from its local directory
- run this script as './unixodbc_setup.sh'

unset ODBCINI and ODBCINSTINI
Adding driver info to /etc/odbcinst.ini...
Adding connect info to /etc/odbc.ini...
- Setup sucessfully!
- Steps to do after running this script
  1. Replace SF_ACCOUNT with the account name in /etc/odbc.ini
  2. (optional) Specify username and password in /etc/odbc.ini
  3. Make sure current users have write permission to the log
     directory.
```

Step 4 - Moving on to the step to configure the ODBC Driver, I check whether the 3 steps outlined in the documentation have been done correctly or not

Step 4.1 - Something doesn't look right in the `simba.snowflake.ini` file. The last part which specifies the Driver manager looks like below.

```
#   unixODBC
ODBCInstLib=/usr/lib64/libodbcinst.so
CABundleFile=/home/ubuntu/snowflake_odbc/lib/cacert.pem
```

I don't think there is a `/usr/lib64/libodbcinst.so` and I go ahead and confirm it doesn't exist. Unfortunately I think my Linux knowledge (or lack of) tops out here and I don't know what to change this to.

Steps 4.2 and 4.3 are pretty straight forward I have changed the required details in `/etc/odbc.ini` to reflect the right server name and account

I'm fairly certain this hasn't set up properly but I try the next step anyway.

Step 5 - Testing the ODBC Driver with `isql -v snowflake my_username my_password` obviously errors out with the following console log

```
[S1000][unixODBC][Snowflake][ODBC] (11560) Unable to locate SQLGetPrivateProfileString function.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Can you please guide me on how to proceed? If I have not specified any details necessary to debug please let me know what else I can add.

Thanks very much!

Comment: A little late, but seeing if you were able to figure this one out.  I've seen a couple people report that error "installed snowflake-odbc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1" but after following the instructions to install on Linux, they eventually figure it out by uninstalling/removing the package and reinstalling. **sudo apt-get install -f** might help as well if dependencies are missing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment! I was able to solve this by downloading a driver that was 1 version before the latest version and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Good to know! Thank you.